# updating database at end of session_set_cookie_params/session.gc_maxlifetime

Tags: php

Is there anyway to trigger an sql logic (essentially a php function containing the sql logic) after the timer that is set in session_set_cookie_params/session.gc_maxlifetime have run out? E.g a user does not log out properly and have closed the browser. So the database is not updated.

Edit: Also a question about session.gc_maxlifetime. Does an automatic ajax request that is not fired because of userinteraction with the browser reset its timer?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839102/how-to-log-user-out-due-to-inactivity or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427410/how-to-know-when-user-closes-browser-chat-application

Comment: I got a question about the answer provided by RKh (last one on my screen). How can I make the script run if the user closes the browser?